# Lanzar programa con Python o con cmd

Tags: python, terminal

Buenas, espero puedan ayudarme.
El hecho es que quiero lanzar un programa con un script con Python. Lo primero que se me vino a la mente era usando el módulo `os` de la librería estándar de Python 3.

Sería algo como:

```
import os 
prom=os.system("start chrome")
```

Esto funciona y , por ejemplo, abre Chrome exitosamente.

Me valgo del modulo `os` en su función `system` para teclear de manera automática que abra Chrome. Pero en el caso de programas no tan conocidos no los abre. Hay que buscar el nombre especifico del archivo .exe y ejecutarlo o añadirlos al path. Corrijanme si me equivoco. Quizás existe otra manera que no sea con `os` .

En resúmen, lo que quiero es poder lanzar programas desde un script de python.

Comment: Busqué un poco y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412852/python-how-to-execute-an-external-program)
 encontré buena información,
 también [aquí](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/) más explicado y con ejemplos, ojalá te sirvan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener mucho más control y comunicación con el proceso usando [`subprocess.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). No bloqueas tu script hasta que el proceso retorne y además puedes comunicarte con el proceso via *stdin* y obtener *stderr*/*stdout* usando tuberias (pipes).

Un ejemplo sería:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe',
                  'https://es.stackoverflow.com/',
                  '-new-tab'])
```

Esto abre Mozilla Firefox o crea una nueva pestaña (si ya está abierto) mostrando la página de SOes.

En este caso se usa una ruta absoluta al ejecutable. También se pueden llamar a procesos que sean reconocidos por su nombre (ver más abajo) o usar rutas relativas al script que lanza el proceso.

Ni el propio comando `start` o `subprocess.popen` realizan una búsqueda cuando se proporciona un nombre de una aplicación simplemente se lo pasan al sistema operativo (via API, por ejemplo usando `ShellExecuteEx`) que se encarga de realizar una búsqueda automática que suele abarcar:

- Directorio de trabajo actual
- Directorio de Windows
- Directorio de Windows \ System32
- Los directorios listados en la variable de entorno PATH
- Rutas de aplicación definidas en el registro

Puedes mirarte el siguiente enlace para más información:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx

Ten en cuenta que no hay forma de que se llame a un ejecutable si este no está en alguno de los directorios anteriores donde pueda ser encontrado por el SO o sin proporcionar la ruta absoluta/relativa al ejecutable. No es cosa de usar una librería u otra o un lenguaje u otro, simplemente eso sería como pedir *"búscame algo que se pueda ejecutar que se llame "ejemplo.exe" y que estará en algún lado en mi sistema de archivos y ejecutalo"*

En tu caso abre Chrome porque en la instalación se agrego la ruta en el registro (posiblemente en `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`), no es un tema de ser un programa más u menos común.

Claro está, que podrias crear un script que se encargara de buscar un determinado ejecutable en unos determinados directorios donde creas que es posible que se encuentre el ejecutable y ejecutarlo si lo encuentra. Algo como lo siguiente, que no es ni lo más seguro ni eficiente y que **solo pretende ser un ejemplo simple**:

```
import os
import subprocess

def ejecutar(file, directorios):
    for ruta in directorios:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ruta):
            if file in files:
                subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(root, file),
                                  'https://es.stackoverflow.com/',
                                  '-new-tab'])
                return

file = 'firefox.exe'
directorios = ['C:/Program Files', 'C:/Users/Fulanito']
ejecutar(file, directorios)
```

Todo esto está referido a Windows como es obvio, en sistemas *nix la cosa es diferente como cabe esperar.

Comment: excelente respuesta amigo gracias. Me ha servido de mucho