# Abrir archivo PDF desde Script Python

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

Tengo un script que ejecuto con Spyder y Anaconda, con el que abro un archivo PDF desde Python con el lector de PDF por defecto, en este caso Acrobat Reader con la siguiente linea:

```
import os
os.popen('Arhivo.pdf')
```

El problema es que he generado un ejecutable de mi código, con la librería Pyinstaller y funciona todo perfecto pero no consigo que me abra el archivo como lo hacía cuando ejecutaba el script desde Spyder con Anaconda. No se si debo usar otra libreria que cree otro 'thread' para abrir el archivo.

¿Cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: prueba con la ruta completa del archivo.

Comment: Ese no es el problema, es que aparte de no abrirlo, aunque cierre mi aplicación intento abrir otro PDF y no se abre, es como si se hubiera quedado colgado el Acrobat Reader, algo muy raro.

Comment: Prueba con subprocess como indica el compañero de SO en esta respuesta
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87915/lanzar-programa-con-python-o-con-cmd